# PHP - Saving form data to two different text files

Tags: php, forms, submit, text-files

I have a simple HTML form comprising of check boxes and text fields.

When I submit this form it submits the data back to the same page where I capture the data and write it to a text file.

What I'd like to try and do is write some of the check box and field data to one text file and the rest to another.

Can this be done ? if it can how do I say which fields are written to which file ?

Thanks

Comment: you write code. `file_put_contents('1.txt', $somevalue); file_put_contents('2.txt', $othervalue);`

Comment: Let's see your code (post it).

Comment: please post your code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you send your form and after that you handle the data. For example:

```
$dog = $_POST["dog"];
$cat = $_POST["cat"];

$fileForDogs = fopen('path://to/first/file', 'a+'); //a+ means if not exst, create one and write on the end of file
fwrite($fileForDogs, $dog);
fclose($fileForDogs);

$fileForCats = fopen('path://to/second/file', 'a+'); //a+ means if not exst, create one and write on the end of file
fwrite($fileForCats, $cat);
fclose($fileForCats);
```

I would highly recommend to look at databases for example mysql to save data from form.